# Copy files with regexp and keep the directory structure

Tags: regex, find, cp

I have a folder which contain subfolders and files.
I use the following code to cp files from one place to another without the file like data.0001 or data.00001 ...

```
find . ! -iregex ".*\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].*" -exec cp {} /destination/folder/ \;
```

The problem is that all the files are copied into the same directory. How can I solve this problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try this shot :

```
find . ! -iregex ".*\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].*" -type f -exec \
  install -D "{}" "/destination/folder/{}" \;
```

Note the `type f` if you are looking for files. Replace 'f' with 'd' if you are looking for directories.